# Is =SUM(E3#) a correct format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have recently seen a sum function with the following format: =SUM(E3#) I don't know how it works but it returns a correct value for a range of numbers, E3:E22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in Excel 365 if **E3** is the top of a dynamic spill-down array.  Using it allows you to "not know" how far down the spill-down goes.